# List of unique values based on a criterion

Tags: google-sheets

I am working on a Google Sheets that has a phrase, assigned number to the phrase and then I want to create a new list on a new column of phrases that have an assigned number less than `5`. Moreover, I do not want phrases repeated:

[image: Screenshot of my sheet]

Currently I have this as my formula in cell E4:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(C4:C25000,SMALL(IF(D4:D25000>5,IF(COUNTIF(C$4:C4,C4:C25000)=0,ROW(C4:C25000)-ROW(C$4)+1)),1)),"")
```

and it is not working.

Could anyone help me to get this right?

<sub>I have access to Excel so that would work too.</sub>

Answer (score 5):

A similar question to this was posted on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48024923/google-sheets-counting-x-where-y-from-column-of-uniques/48025066#48025066).

Try this:

`=UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A, B2:B < 5))`

Answer (score 0):

Also a useful extension to ale's formula would be incorporating it into multiple lists using  ";".

```
=(unique({filter(A2:A,B2:B>5);filter(C2:C,$D2:D>5)})
```